# Dockerizing Maven Application

Tags: docker, maven, war

I have a Spring application in which we use Maven. For good practices we removed the target folder which contains the libraries and the war file. Our current Dockerfile is:

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY . .
WORKDIR .

RUN mvn clean install
RUN mvn clean package

COPY . .

FROM icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:full-java11-openj9-ubi

COPY --chown=1001:0 src/main/liberty/config/ /config/
COPY --chown=1001:0 target/apcc-backend-microservices.war /config/apps/

RUN configure.sh
```

This is a screenshot of my containers log:
[image]

I don't understand why it says it was created the war file:

```
[INFO] Building war: /target/apcc-backend-microservices.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

but it then says its not there:

```
error building at STEP "COPY --chown=1001:0 target/apcc-backend-microservices.war /config/apps/": checking on sources under "/tmp/builder/1cd5d996-913d-4662-8191-69fe1ad63f7e": copier: stat: "/target/apcc-backend-microservices.war": no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was switching container, so the war file was created in the maven container but I was then moving go the liberty container. For this I had to specify from which container I was pulling the war file:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY . .
WORKDIR .

RUN mvn clean package

FROM icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:full-java11-openj9-ubi

COPY --from=build src/main/liberty/config/ /config/
COPY --from=build target/apcc-backend-microservices.war /config/apps/

EXPOSE 9080

RUN configure.sh
```